# extract data date wise and do average calculation

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

How to extract data date wise and do average calculation per date from the below shown output. last column is average.

```
Sun Jul  5 00:00:02 IST 2015, 97
Sun Jul  5 00:02:01 IST 2015, 97
Sun Jul  5 00:04:02 IST 2015, 97
Mon Jul  6 00:00:01 IST 2015, 73
Mon Jul  6 00:02:02 IST 2015, 93
Mon Jul  6 00:04:02 IST 2015, 97
Tue Jul  7 00:00:02 IST 2015, 97
Tue Jul  7 00:02:02 IST 2015, 97
Tue Jul  7 00:04:01 IST 2015, 97
Wed Jul  8 00:00:01 IST 2015, 98
Wed Jul  8 00:02:02 IST 2015, 98
Wed Jul  8 00:04:01 IST 2015, 98
Thu Jul  9 00:00:02 IST 2015, 100
Thu Jul  9 00:02:01 IST 2015, 100
Thu Jul  9 00:04:01 IST 2015, 100
Fri Jul 10 00:00:01 IST 2015, 100
Fri Jul 10 00:02:02 IST 2015, 100
Fri Jul 10 00:04:02 IST 2015, 100
Sat Jul 11 00:00:01 IST 2015, 73
Sat Jul 11 00:02:01 IST 2015, 73
Sat Jul 11 00:04:02 IST 2015, 73
```

want output as

```
Jun  6 - 97
Jun  7 - 86.66
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F ', ' '{
   split($1, a, " ");
   k=a[2] OFS a[3];
   if(!(k in c))
      b[++n]=k;
   c[k]++;
   sum[k]+=$2
}
END{
   for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
      printf "%s - %.2f\n", b[i], (sum[b[i]]/c[b[i]])
}' file
Jul 5 - 97.00
Jul 6 - 87.67
Jul 7 - 97.00
Jul 8 - 98.00
Jul 9 - 100.00
Jul 10 - 100.00
Jul 11 - 73.00
```

Comment: another query, how to get the average between the given dates ?

for example what the average between Jul 5 to Jun 11 ?

Comment: Date calculation will be tricky for the cases when months cross over or years cross over. I suggest creating a new question since date calculation won't be easy for given input.